# Automating SQL server reports execution

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services

Hi I have question is there any way to automatically execute SSRS reports for example user goes to ssrs and put some parameters to execute reports and exports them in excel and pdf . Is there any way to avoid human interaction and automate the whole process or any job in C# code runs automatically reports and exports them in format.

Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't want to use subscriptions, you can write your own program in C# to pass the parameters and render the report and save in whatever format you like. Then run this using Windows scheduler or however you want to.

It is quite easy and [Microsoft have some example code to get you started](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/reportexecution2005.reportexecutionservice.render.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=csharp#code-snippet-1).

Answer (score 3):

A Reporting Services subscription is a configuration that delivers a report at a specific time or in response to an event, and in a file format that you specify. For example, every Wednesday, save the MonthlySales.rdl report as a Microsoft Word document to a file share.

Subscriptions can be used to schedule and automate the delivery of a report and with a specific set of report parameter values.

You can create multiple subscriptions for a single report to vary the subscription options; for example, you can specify different parameter values to produce three versions of a report, such as a Western region sales report, Eastern region sales, and all sales.

FROM: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms159762.aspx

And for how to configure a subscription to deliver a report by e-mail, check here http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc872783.aspx

And if you need to do programmatically, you can start here http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/36009/Programmatically-Playing-With-SSRS-Subscriptions

Comment: thank you for your mail i know it but my problem is to execute automatically a report by filling required parameters from a list and export those reports automatically in Excel .

Comment: Check "Passing Parameter Values from the Subscriber Database to the Report" from the following link http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms155972(v=sql.105).aspx